# Labels inside a input

Tags: css, html, forms

How to put form labels inside a input form only on mobile?

**example:**

[image]

**my code:**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="firstName">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="lastName">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Lastname" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="phone_number">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="A valid 9 or 10 digit phone number" maxlength="10"required pattern="0[689]?[0-9]{8}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: Or leave both in normal flow, and simply apply the border and background “around them” (you already have a grouping element around them), instead of on the individual elements ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? I changed the position of `input` and `label` in the HTML

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 3.5em;
}

input.form-control {
  height: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

label.form-control-label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" required />
    <label class="form-control-label" for="firstName">Firstname</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Lastname" required />
    <label class="form-control-label" for="lastName">Lastname</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="A valid 9 or 10 digit phone number" maxlength="10" required pattern="0[689]?[0-9]{8}" />
    <label class="form-control-label" for="phone_number">Mobile Number</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like the below method. We have to write mobile screen style with in the media queries

```css
body{
font-family:arial;
}
.form-group{
position:relative;
}
.input-element{
padding:30px 5px 5px 5px;
width:100%;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.label-element{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px;
font-size:12px;
color:#666;

}
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group"><label class="label-element">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="input-element"/></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by another answer, here is a short way to do it:

```css
.input-group {
    position: relative;
}
.input-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    color: #666;
}
.input-element {
    padding: 30px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-label">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-element" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just added a border to `form-group` and overwritten some bootstrap code.

For mobile only, try to use [CSS3 Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

You could try this:

```css
.form-group {
  border: 1px solid black; /* Change border width and color here */
}

/* the !important declaration is for this snippet, because this snippet include bootstrap after this declarations **/
.form-control {
  border: none !important; /* No border for input */
  box-shadow: none !important; /* No border for input */
}

.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important; /* Remove the blue shining at focus */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="firstName">Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="lastName">Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Lastname" required />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="phone_number">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="A valid 9 or 10 digit phone number" maxlength="10" required pattern="0[689]?[0-9]{8}" />
  </div>
</form>
```